# No matches for kind "ExternalMetric" in version "metrics.aws/v1alpha1"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, yaml, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I'm getting an error when attempting to deploy an external metric monitor for AWS SQS. I'm attempting to deploy this in EKS 1.15. Currently it works in my EKS 1.14 environment.

`unable to recognize "app-deployment.yml": no matches for kind "ExternalMetric" in version "metrics.aws/v1alpha1"`

Here is my yaml file. I'm not sure where I goofed in here especially since it works in another cluster but of a different version.

```yaml
apiVersion: metrics.aws/v1alpha1
kind: ExternalMetric
metadata:
  name: app-offline-queue-length
  namespace: myNamespace
spec:
  name: app-offline-queue-length
  resource:
    resource: "deployment"
  queries:
    - id: sqs_realtime_length
      metricStat:
        metric:
          namespace: "AWS/SQS"
          metricName: "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"
          dimensions:
            - name: QueueName
              value: "app-myname-offline"
        period: 300
        stat: Average
        unit: Count
      returnData: true
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have different sets of CRDs in both clusters? Can you do `kubectl get crd` in both clusters and compare the results?

Comment: yep that was it. I didn't catch the 'kind' difference under names. Its squared away now, thank you!